# Splitting a string in Pig in a column and then storing it in a row

Tags: split, apache-pig, etl

I have a csv file which contains 4 columns of data but has 250000 rows.

```
A          B      C     D               
Tom        1      x    Blah Blah Blah
Bob        2      y    Blah <p> Blah
Jane       3      z    Blah, &p *£
Harry      4      a    Blah "p" Blah
```

In col 4 I have a string that contains a variety of characters, some code, some special characters, some text.

I would like to take each word in D and combine it with the contents in A and store it in a new row i.e

```
Tom Blah
Tom Blah
Tom Blah
Bob Blah
Bob <p>
Bob Blah
Jane Blah,
Jane &p
Jane *£
Harry Blah
Harry "p"
Harry Blah
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#strsplit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [STRSPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#strsplit) and [TOBAG](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#tobag) to convert the value in the 4th column of your data set to first split the data and convert it into rows.Finally [CONCAT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#concat) the resulting 2 columns with ' '.

**Pig Script**

```
A = LOAD 'test6.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (f1:chararray,f2:chararray,f3:chararray,f4:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE f1,FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(f4,' '));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0,FLATTEN(TOBAG($1,$2,$3));
D = FOREACH C GENERATE CONCAT($0,CONCAT(' ',$1));
DUMP D;;
```

**Output**

[image: TOBAG]

Comment: I think OP just mean a row with two columns `A` and `D_token`, not a row of string. So just flattening is enough. I also roughly recalling flattening on strsplit is fine.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Thanks for taking the time to respond I'm very grateful. What I forgot to mention in my OP is that the string in column D is of variable length so there's not just three words in that column, there could be a hundred in some cases. What is the best way to mange this? Could I perform a count of the number of words in the string and then loop for this number of times so that Tom is concatenated with each word in the string from Col D?

Comment: @WolfPig It doesn't matter how big the string is as long as the string is delimited consistently it will work,unless the string is larger than a block of hdfs.

Comment: @WolfPig Sorry,I take that back,I commented without looking at the fact that I had used $1,$2,$3.I don't have access to the cluster but will test it out tomorrow.You will have to slightly modify the relation B and C.B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(f4,' '));
C = FOREACH B GENERATE A.$0,FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));